# Getting null value instead of Id from View to Edit action method

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

Getting 'null' from List View to Edit/Details/Delete Action method instead of the Id.

In List view, in Id column it shows corresponding Id without any issues. In All.cshtml file,

```
<td>
   @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ModifiedOn)
</td>
<td>
   @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.CategoryId }) |
   @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.CategoryId }) |
   @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.CategoryId })
</td>
```

And Edit method is,

```
public ActionResult Edit(int? id) {
   if (id == null) {
      return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
      return View();
   }
   var editCategory = new PetaPoco.Database("DefaultConnection");
   var category = editCategory.Single<CategoryViewModels>("SELECT * FROM Category WHERE   
              CategoryId=@0 AND IsActive = 1", id);
   return View(category);
}
```

The Url in the browser is, /Category/Edit/C1. But in Edit/Details/Delete, the Id is null.

What am I missing?

Thanks.

Comment: its null because as you said,t he URL contains "C1" as the last parameter... this is not of type int. make sure the data types match.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the url can be `/Category/Edit/C1`, the `id` parameter in the controller action method can't be an `int?`. Try to change the type of `id` to string

```
public ActionResult Edit(string id) {
   if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(id)) {
      return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
      return View();
   }
   var editCategory = new PetaPoco.Database("DefaultConnection");
   var category = editCategory.Single<CategoryViewModels>("SELECT * FROM Category WHERE   
              CategoryId=@0 AND IsActive = 1", id);
   return View(category);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

the "C1" is not type of int, convert it to "int?" will get null.